# c++ type arguments are omitted in template declaration. However, how about in the definition of member function?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Sorry that I'm a beginner of c++ programming.

As I know, the type arguments in template declaration can be omitted. For example

```
template<typename T>
class A{
A<T> func(A<T> t);
}
```

can be written as

```
template<typename T>
class A{
A func(A t) {}
}
```

Also, I know that if the member functions are defined outside of the class, the type arguments cannot be omitted. However, I found that the type argument in the function's argument type can be omitted as well. Why is it like this?

I mean for

```
A<T> A<T>:: func(A<T> t) {}
```

why the code below is permissible even though it's outside the template declaration?

```
A<T> A<T>:: func(A t) {}
```

Comment: The "duplicate" does not answer this question. OP is aware that the injected classname exists, the question is why it works outside the class' body.

Comment: Oh sorry those should be  A<T> A<T>:: func(A<T> t) {} and A<T> A<T>:: func(A t) {}

Comment: Approximately, the compiler reads code from left to right. When it sees `A<T>::`, it knows that we are inside `A<T>` again, so it can assume that an `A` without parameters really means `A<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this works is because `A<T>::` scopes the declaration -- everything that follows it knows about the contents of `A<T>`, including the injected classname `A`. This is also strictly in source code order, leading to the following curiosity between two semantically identical definitions:

```
A A<T>::func(A t) {} // Doesn't work -- `A` is not known before `A<T>::`

auto A<T>::func(A t) -> A {} // Works, because the return type is after `A<T>::`!
```

Comment: Which, IIRC, was a big reason for the introduction of the `auto f(args) -> type` syntax.

Comment: @DanielH It's also much appreciated when you want to use the parameters in the return type, e.g. `template <class T, class U> auto f(T a, U b) -> decltype(a + b)`.

Comment: I was considering that as part of the same reason, but an example of where it’s more useful. Doing this puts the return type at a point where more things are in scope, so you can just use `A` or `decltype(a + b)` instead of `A<T>` or `decltype(declval<T>() + declval<U>())`.